# Can you get duplicate standees from the Poplin Shop?

Tags: super-mario-bros-wonder

When I buy a Standee Surprise from the Poplin Shop it gives me a random Standee. Is it possible to get a duplicate Standee I already have?

[image: Standee Surprise in Poplin Shop]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find duplicate standees buying from Poplin Shop. But this can be avoided with Special Poplin Shop, which is found in

> Special World

The Special shop sells Character Standee Surprise, that gives you a specific character's standee "that you don't have yet". As explained in the item description:

[image]

Comment: I realized that this was already stated by Jeff Mercado in the comment section (d'oh), but I think it's worth to be an answer anyway

Comment: I somehow failed to read that it gives you a standee you don't have.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get duplicates. You can tell if a newly purchased standee is a duplicate if it's missing a "New" marker.

There seems to be a boosted chance of getting unique standees, as even when I'd collected nearly every standee I usually wouldn't get more than a few duplicates in a row.

New Standee
[image: New Standee]

Duplicate Standee
[image: Duplicate Standee]

Comment: The Standee Surprise will pick something at random across all standees. I don't expect them to be weighted toward ones you don't have, I stopped buying the surprise once I was getting dupes too frequently (~60% completion). You'll want to save it for when you reach Special World where the shop there will allow you to buy a random standee for a character that you don't already have. But it'll cost ya 30 purple coins each.

Comment: I managed to get 100% completion buying only surprise standees. It seemed to be weighted as I got closer to the end. I did buy from the special world, so maybe that had an effect.